# How to use front camera using mediaConfig of navigator.getUserMedia for webRTC

Tags: javascript, webrtc

guys

I am searching how to use front camera on Android Chrome. I referred to javascript getUserMedia configuration (document : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)

I found {facingMode : "user"} makes front camera be selected in document, but I couldn't solve it.

I tried like this. please give me the reason why it is failed.

1. mediaConfig modified.

> ```
> mediaConfig : {
>    video: {
>         mandatory: {
>             maxWidth : 1280,
>               maxHeight : 720,
>               minWidth : 1280,
>               minHeight : 720
>         },
>         optional: [{
>               facingMode: 'user' 
>         }]
>        },
>   audio : true,
> },
> ```

2. caller

> ```
>   navigator.getUserMedia(nextRTC.mediaConfig, 
>     function(stream) {
>               nextRTC.localStream = stream;
>               nextRTC.call('localStream', {
>                   stream : stream
>               });
>               nextRTC.request(sessionId, null, 'initialize', null, null);
>           }, error);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `facingMode: { exact: "user" }`.

Comment: This is not the solution.        
optional: [{
              facingMode: { exact: "user" }
        }]
Is there any other way to solve?